# iptable for port forwarding

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, iptables, portforwarding

I want to redirect all trafic coming to my Linux (`192.168.1.34`) on the port 22 to another address

So I used the following iptable command

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.239:22
```

the command does not return error.

But when I try to open ssh session from a PC (`192.168.1.133`) to my linux (`192.168.1.34`), the ssh session is not opened. It looks like the ssh trafic is not redirected to (`192.168.1.239`)

If I open the ssh session directly from the PC (`192.168.1.133`) to the (`192.168.1.239`), then the session is opened

Comment: What is the network mask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure the NAT host has IP forwarding enabled:

```
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Second, all your hosts are on the same subnet which means, the SSH traffic from `192.168.1.239` back to your client (`192.168.1.133`) is NOT routed via `192.168.1.34`.

So you can either:

1. use both DNAT and SNAT, or
2. use different subnets for your hosts.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add two more rules: your Linux IP (**192.168.1.34**) and another machine's IP (**192.168.1.239**):

```
### \# prerouting
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.239:22

### \# postrouting
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 22 -j MASQUERADE

### \# forward
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.1.34 -d 192.168.1.239 -j ACCEPT

sudo iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.1.239 -d 192.168.1.34 -j ACCEPT
```